# MYSQL triggers and "FOR EACH ROW"

Tags: mysql, database

When creating MYSQL triggers, what does "FOR EACH ROW" do? What would happen if you left it out? What are some things you could replace it with and what would they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"FOR EACH ROW" is just part of the syntax. 
It is there just to remind you that the trigger will actually act on EACH ROW. That's it.

You cannot omitted because you will receive an error.